# Insensetive thread safe Map doesnt work properly

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap, concurrenthashmap, concurrentskiplistmap

I have ConcurrentSkipListMap with insensetive key feaure:

```
public static ConcurrentMap<String, GooglePlayGame> games = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, GooglePlayGame>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

If i run my app first time and will add to map user request, f.e. i completed --games.put("Oddmar", ...) --, if user after this will request --/game oddmar (odDmar or whatever)-- it will works, but.. I always load my map from json file at start in static block:

```
static {
        TypeFactory typeFactory = mapper.getTypeFactory();
        MapType mapType = typeFactory.constructMapType(ConcurrentSkipListMap.class, String.class, GooglePlayGame.class);
        try {
            games = mapper.readValue(new File(
                    "gpgames_library.json"), mapType);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If after "restart" user will try /game oddmar, it will not works - only /game Oddmar. But why? If in app i always read map from my variable (not from file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your "TypeFactory" creates the map, it doesn't use `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` but the natural order. I don't know what your "TypeFactory" is but one way to sidestep the problem is to read the JSON into a temporary value and then using `putAll` to add what was read from the JSON file into your `games` map.

```
Map<String, GooglePlayGame> temporary = mapper.readValue(new File(
          "gpgames_library.json"), mapType);
games.putAll(temporary);
```

Comment: Without this TypeFactory sometimes my some fields in json file was "null".  Jackson couldnt read my class properly, and i found this solution. 

Thanks, this works, but what about perfomance? If i have a ton of object putAll + read from files will take a lot of time, i guess.

Comment: How often is this done, once per app run right? If it was once per animation frame I might worry about it but once per run, no

Comment: Once per app run. While app is active, i always read/write to/from my local map. When i get new request (if it doesnt exist in map), i'll add this request to file in other thread.